# Is it me or my ISP?: Persistent 503 Service Unavailable Problems

Tags: windows, dns, http

For months now I keep getting 503s when I attempt to visit 3 websites.

My ISP keeps trying to blame my computer and not its system. I have bought two modems in the past 15 months on the ISPs recommendation and the problem persists. The problem involves getting 503 Service Unavailable messages at the same three sites off and on. I am using a big desktop H-P with Win7. The problem occurs with all 3 browsers: FF,Chrome, and IE.

One of the three sites I get the 503s for is www.Tumblr.com.

I have lost 30+ hours calling techsupport at my ISP.

No one but me has access to this machine.

The 503 issue is sporadic. For 5 to 7 days I can't access these 3 sites, then for a few days I can. Then the 503s come back again.

Nothing we do with the modem fixes the problem although completely restoring it by pushing a paperclip into the hole in the back appears to fix the problem for a short bit.
The modem is the ISP's (Centurylink) custom model.

By the way, I check the three sites with those "Is it up or down" websites and they all confirm that the sites I can't reach are up.

Is it me or the ISP?  I understand that 503s point to the website's servers as the trouble spot, but could it be my computer?

This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 6):

The [HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) are never produced by your web browser, it simply displays them when they are returned by a web server; a 503 error shouldn't be produced by your computer, ever (well, unless your computer *is* the web server, obviously).

But for the same reason, it could not be caused by your ISP: if you actually had connection problems, you would get an error in your browser stating it can't connect to the server, or the request timed out, or something similar; but ***not*** a HTTP error, which can be returned only by the remote end of the connection, i.e. the web server.

And yet, it's very unlikely those errors are actually coming from the sites you're browsing, otherwise you wouldn't be the only person complaining about them. If Tumblr was actually having issues, someone would have noticed.

The only possible explanation I can find points to you using a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server), which is returning the error; if you have a proxy configured in your browser, try turning it off or changing it to another one; if you are not using any proxy, then only two options remain: either your ISP is putting your web traffic through a transparent proxy without telling you about it, or there is some software on your computer which is doing the same thing, possibly a malware. If it's a transparent proxy, it could also be running on your modem (again, without your knowledge).

Comment: As an added point, many viruses will automatically install a proxy onto your computer, so that your data is rerouted to websites that you don't intend to send data to (malicious websites). Make sure your antivirus software is up-to-date, and check your computer for viruses.

Comment: Many ISPs run transparent proxies. If those are acting up, it would explain it.